# while creating environment on kubernetes using jenkins x , Failed to create repository due to POST https://api.github.com/user/repos: 404 Not Found []

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, local, minikube

I have created cluster using minikube on local.Have installed jx on cluster but unable to create a staging or production environment
** jx create env **
Error : `error: Failed to create repository /environment-jx-prod due to: POST https://api.github.com/user/repos: 404 Not Found []`

Comment: Can you get to https://api.github.com/user/repos ? Just wondering if you're behind a firewall. Have you tried it more than once and have you tried with `--git-username=`?

Comment: yes have tried with ` jx create env --git-username = my_user_name` but still giving same error. please help me.

api.github.com/user/repos  is showing 
`
{
  "message": "Requires authentication",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories"
}`

Comment: Maybe you don't have a token set up. It should use by default if you have configured https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/ or you can get one and then use `--git-api-token=` option

Comment: I have checked the token scenarios but it is not that. They have different error codes. @SarikaJamdade can you provide more steps to recreate? You have first created minikube cluster and then have ran `jx create env`?